# C# Webbrowser - Can't get element by ID

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, element, getelementbyid

I Can't retrive element while using GetElementby Id in Webbrowser controller;
Webpag code is:

```
<tr class="tb_item02" align="left">
<td width="15%" class="tb_title" align="right">Set as :</td>
<td width="35%">
<select id="set_AS" name="set_AS" class="select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No" selected="">No</option>
</select>
</td>

<td width="15%" class="tb_title" align="right">Re-Generate:</td>
<td width="35%">
<select id=" Regenerate" name="Regenerate" class="select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No" selected="">No</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

As I try to get `set_AS` Element by:

```
HtmlElement reportDropDown = wbrsr.Document.GetElementById("set_AS");
HtmlElementCollection elCol = reportDropDown.GetElementsByTagName("option");
```

`reportDropDown` stays `null` and `elcol` is throwing:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any suggestion what am I missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved :)

Nasted the

```
HtmlElement reportDropDown = wbrsr.Document.GetElementById("set_AS");
HtmlElementCollection elCol = reportDropDown.GetElementsByTagName("option");
```

within try snippt,
and at the catch event, fired another     HtmlElement reportDropDown = wbrsr.Document.GetElementById("set_AS");
    HtmlElementCollection elCol = reportDropDown.GetElementsByTagName("option");

Comment: What does "nasted" mean? Urban Dictionary gives a definition, but I don't think it's what you meant.